# Delete single item using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please I need to delete item from my website using jQuery and ajax but I don't know how to get the particular id of what I want to delete or less is single see below example:

**HTML CODE**

```
<span id="file-1">Orange</span> <a id="delete-1">Delete</a>
<span id="file-2">Orange</span> <a id="delete-2">Delete</a>
<span id="file-3">Orange</span> <a id="delete-3">Delete</a>
<span id="file-4">Orange</span> <a id="delete-4">Delete</a>
<span id="file-5">Orange</span> <a id="delete-5">Delete</a>
<!--Next item will have id of 6 is looping...-->
```

**AJAX JQUERY**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $("#delete-").click(function(){
//Am confused here how to know which id need to be deleted?
var id = $('#file-').val();
        $.ajax({
        url:'/delete_reply.php',
        data:'id='+id,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(){
        $('#comment-'+id'').attr('class', 'deleting');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#comment-'+id'').hide();
            $(#comment-'+id'').css('display','none'); 

        }
          });
          });
    });
</script>
```

Please I don't know how to pass the id of the content I want to delete to the ajax can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want to delete the `anchor` tag which was clicked? Or you want to identify which of anchors was clicked out of those 5 and send that delete request?

Comment: @NikhilPatil I think OP wants to delete a corresponding entry from the database otherwise why use AJAX?

Comment: Yes, i want to delete the span with the same id of delete button @NikhilPatil

Comment: The ajax will send the id to my php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your

```
var id = $('#file-').val();
```

with

```
var id=$(this).attr('id').split("-")[1];
```

Btw, I haven't tested rest of your code. Particularly, your `#delete-` selector that you have used for binding click event.

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE:

> It's good approach to assign value to HTML element using **data
>   attributes**. 
> For that HTML and jQuery both would look something like
>   follow.

**HTML:**

```
<span id="file-3">Orange</span> <a data-fileid="3" class="cmnDeleteFile">Delete</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".cmnDeleteFile").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id=$(this).data('fileid');
    // This is how you get id of the file from same element using data attribute.

});
```

---

### Old answer:

You're following wrong method.
Give every link common CSS class and fire trigger event on click of a link like this.

**HTML:**

```
<span id="file-3">Orange</span> <a id="3" class="cmnDeleteFile">Delete</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".cmnDeleteFile").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    // This is how you get id of the file from same element.

});
```

Comment: Okay boss wait i check the method

Comment: @Alok: I agree with your overall approach but not with your naming scheme for `id`. You have two elements here with id 3 and that will cause problems sometime or the other (and of course, it's invalid html)

Comment: @NikhilPatil Yeah we generally use `data-` to assign values to html elements, but it is much cleaner then the current approach or doing split. And off course file won't have the same ID as link, that was typo, corrected in my last edit.

Comment: @Alok Yup, using `data-` would be much better than both approaches. Perhaps you should update your answer with that

Comment: @NikhilPatil yeah that's nice idea, updated the answer.